# AutoHotKey equivalent? (paste timestamp, open app, external keyboard, etc.)

Tags: applications, keyboard, home-screen-shortcuts, keyboard-shortcuts

Desktop PCs have AutoHotKey, AutoKey, IronKey, etc. .

But as far as known, **nothing compareable for mobile phones.**

I would like to be able to do things like:

- Instantly pasting timestamp in preferred date format (i.e.20180210115759 or 10.02.2018 11h:59m:19s) using a keyboard shortcut from an external Bluetooth/USB-OTG powered keyboard.
- Pasting tinestamp with on-screen keyboard (without any bulky workaround such as copying to the limited clipboard first).

  - Open/switch to application (e.g. text editor) using keyboaed shortcut.
- Ability to launch selected app directly from external keyboard hotkey to take notes using a portable bluetooth keyboard while the phone is still inside the pocket. http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/190819/allow-running-specific-applications-without-unlocking?noredirect=1#comment246822_190819

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Please note we don't welcome software recommendation questions. You can try our sister site, [softwarerecs.se].

Comment: @iBug It does not necessarily have to be software. Just a solution.