# Allow running specific applications without unlocking?

Tags: applications, lock-screens, lock-screen-widgets

I would like to have access to selected applications directly from lockscreen, without needing to unlock the phone.

- Calculator.
- Stopwatch.
- ASR Voice recorder (only record, no playback) (camera is already possible).
- Selected text editor for quickly taking text notes.
- 3rdParty strobe (flashlight already works)

Comment: Which Android version?

Comment: @BeeShyams: 4.3, 4.4.2, 6.0 and 7.0. In what way does that matter? :)

Comment: @TechLord A lot of ways. If the means of doing stuff didn't change from version to version, there wouldn't be a need for versions don't you think?

Comment: You know the lockscreen itself changes *drastically* between Android versions *and* between different manufacturer UIs, right?

Comment: I forgot mentioning 5.0

Comment: @SarpSTA @ AndyYan Thanks for explaining. Is there a solution, that adapts to each version? (not necessarily but just a bonus)